# File does not upload to Report Server

Tags: c#, report, webclient, reportserver

I am trying to upload a report from the file system to the report server, but for some reason the report doesn't appear when I upload it

Here is the section of code:

```
WebClient reptserv = new WebClient();
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\HereGoesNothing.rdl", lines);
        Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost/reportserver");
        reptserv.UploadFileAsync(address, @"C:\HereGoesNothing.rdl");
```

The report runs in report builder just fine, so I know that's not the issue, but after that I'm stumped.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if you can post it with the WebClient given that it's a virtual directory etc., but I assume you've investigated that. I would add an UploadFileCompleted event to see what it returns (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfilecompleted.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the below so question's answer, this is a better method of achieving what you want to do... 
[Upload a report file to Report manager via .net application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490875/upload-a-report-file-to-report-manager-via-net-application)

Basically you add a service reference to the report server and then upload it via the proxy class, also look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237438%28SQL.80%29.aspx

```
public static void createReport()
{
  ReportingService rs = new ReportingService();
  rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

  Byte[] definition = null;
  Warning[] warnings = null;
  string name = "HereGoesNothing";

  try
  {
     FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\HereGoesNothing.rdl");
     definition = new Byte[stream.Length];
     stream.Read(definition, 0, (int) stream.Length);
     stream.Close();
  }

  catch(IOException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }

  try
  {
     warnings = rs.CreateReport(name, "/", false, definition, null);

     if (warnings != null)
     {
        foreach (Warning warning in warnings)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(warning.Message);
        }
     }

     else
        Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} created successfully with no warnings", name);
  }

  catch (SoapException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString());
  }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be what I need, the only difference is that I am using SS 2008 R2 so I would need to use the ReportingService2010 class.  However the class doesn't exist and I've found a few other people who have had the same issue.   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/3433247c-d87c-4b6d-85d7-eeee40c6ce00  Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried adding it as follows: http://<Server Name>/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx). Please remember to mark the answer as correct if it works

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing, the class just doesn't seem to exist.  I will mark it as right if it works, I just haven't been able to try it yet because of this issue.

Comment: I don't have R2 but try this, instead of adding a service reference, add a web reference: right click service reference --> advanced --> Add Web Reference, and then add http://<Server Name>/reportserver/reportservice2010.asmx?wsdl, Remember the service name you give it. Then try accessing the class (Either ReportService or ReportExecution service maybe). So if you named your service rs then rs.ReportExecutionService sr = new rs.ReportExecutionService();

Comment: I managed to get it working actually using the command prompt method, but for some reason they deprecated the CreateReport method, so now I'm trying to figure out how to do this still.  Since you did answer my question I will mark it as right, but if you have any insight as to the new way to do this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Cool, where did you see that it's depreciated? I can't think of an easy alternative from code, it's funny though because the whitepaper for R2 still uses loadreport http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793463.aspx

Comment: I just remember using the rs (http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/tarad/archive/2005/01/05/3944.aspx) application to automate deploying reports but way too big a mission

Comment: No I solved it, they just changed the name of the method and made it more generic, so it is now the CreateCatalogItem method that is used for this functionality.  Not as intuitive of a name, so it took me a bit to settle on the right one